# Bridging Amazon EC2 With Netplan (18.04)

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, amazon-ec2

I *have* tried looking through this site, and google for a solution before anyone asks. I've made numerous attempts to make a bridged network on my Amazon EC2 server with no success. I've tried

My "stock" config is as follows:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens5:
          dhcp4: true
          match:
           macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          set-name: ens5
```

All my attempts left me with no connection.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What will you be doing with this bridged network, and what are the symptoms of your lack of success?

Comment: Using the bridged network to experiment with a panel I’m making. The symptoms are always no internet after applying. (No SSH until reset)

Comment: Are any of the examples available at `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples` helpful? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Show me `ip a` or `ifconfig`. Where do you define the bridge? Do you have an assigned static IP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this... enter the same MAC in both places... use `ip a` or `ifconfig` to get MAC address...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens5:
      match:
        macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      set-name: ens5
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      interfaces:
        - ens5
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`